# Gmagick fails to install from source

Tags: php, ubuntu, gmagick

I'm trying to install gmagick php extension from source, using these commands:

```
mkdir gmagick
cd gmagick
mkdir build
mkdir local

cd $HOME/gmagick/build
wget ftp://ftp.graphicsmagick.org/pub/GraphicsMagick/1.3/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18.tar.gz
tar zxvf GraphicsMagick-1.3.18.tar.gz
cd GraphicsMagick-1.3.18
./configure --prefix=$HOME/gmagick/local --enable-shared --enable-symbol-prefix
make
make install
export PATH=$HOME/gmagick/local/bin:$PATH

cd $HOME/gmagick/build
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/gmagick-1.1.2RC1.tgz
tar zxvf gmagick-1.1.2RC1.tgz
cd gmagick-1.1.2RC1
phpize
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/gmagick/local/lib/pkgconfig
./configure --prefix=$HOME/gmagick/local --with-gmagick=$HOME/gmagick/local
make
make install
echo "extension=gmagick.so" > /etc/php5/conf.d/gmagick.ini

service php5-fpm restart
```

The lines below contain the command that tests if is installed correctly and it's output.

```
php -i | grep gmagick
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/gmagick.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/gmagick.so: undefined symbol: MagickBlurImage in Unknown on line 0
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gmagick.ini,
PWD => /root/gmagick/build/gmagick-1.1.2RC1
OLDPWD => /root/gmagick/build
_SERVER["PWD"] => /root/gmagick/build/gmagick-1.1.2RC1
_SERVER["OLDPWD"] => /root/gmagick/build
```

Comment: you may ask this question in http://askubuntu.com/..
better useful for you